# C# Sockets programming, received sockets length isn't correct

Tags: java, c#, sockets, asynchronous, byte

I'm doing a chat application between C# clients and a java server.

**I need to send a lot of sockets from the server to the client** when he connects. I want to send the logs of the day. So I have all logs in a file.txt, and I send them to the new connected client.

**For sending them, I have a for loop until all the logs are sent.** Here is the loop:

```
    for (String item : Logs) {
        client.send("log:" + item);
    }
```

And for the **send method**:

```
public void send(String text) {
    //'os' is the: Socket.getOutputStream();
    //What the server will send to the client
    PrintWriter Out = new PrintWriter(os);
    //              0 is the offset, not needed
    Out.write(text, 0, text.length());
    Out.flush();
    System.out.println(text.length());
}
```

**So until there, all works well.**

Now my problem is: The output stream sends bytes length like '30', '100', '399' who is 'text.length()', and the C# client receive all sockets, but **paste 2 or 3 sockets in one**.

E.g: if I send with **separated sockets** (each line is a out.write() and out.flush() because I call the send method for each line)
*(Server-side)*

```
log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789101112131415
log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789101
log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617
log:abcdefghijklmnopqrst
log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvu
```

The **sockets** will be **at the end**:
*(Client-side)*

```
log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789101112131415log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzlog:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789101

log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567891011121314151617log:abcdefghijklmnopqrst

log:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzyxwvu
```

And if I check the **sockets length** in the **server side** I get like;

```
20
12
15
17
20
```

But in the **client side**;

```
32
15
37
```

**The sum of multiples sockets put together..** (And sometimes it's 3 sockets put together, and sometimes 2, sometime 4...) I cant understand why...

Here's **my Async method** for **receiving the sockets from the server**;

```
    private void callBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
    {
        String message = "";
        try
        {
            int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref ip);
            if (size > 0)
            {
                byte[] receive = new byte[size];
                receive = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                message = Encoding.Default.GetString(receive, 0, size);
                Debug.WriteLine(message.Length);
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            //restart the async task
            sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref ip, new AsyncCallback(callBack), buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
```

Where the int 'size' contains the size of the byte[] received, and here is the problem. How can I get the right sockets I sent from the server?

**If I send each socket with delay in the server side** (like 15ms), the **client** can **get the sockets one by one**. But **only if you have a good connection**. If your connection do like 200ms of latency, you will get the sockets grouped... **So the problem is in the client side** (I think...). The server (java) side works correctly, the flush method always send the socket!

**UPDATE:**

Here are my **sockets**;

```
    //Global var
    EndPoint ip;
    public Socket sck;

    //How I connect my sockets
    private void connect()
    {
        ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), mysql.selectPort());
        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            sck.Connect(ip);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, (since **years ago**) you **can** put a C# app in a Linux server. Second, you **don't** send/receive sockets, rather use them to send/receive data.

Comment: Yes I send data and not sockets, It was an error in my writing, but you didn't answer to my question.

Comment: Can you show how `sck` is declared? It sounds like you're communicating over UDP instead of TCP.

Comment: I added my socket declaration on the thread. But if I send a single data it's works. So I don't think the problem is the socket connection, but how I receive the data from the server. Maybe the Async result is slower than the server who send datas so he's overflooded and needs to put some datas in the same result?? Because with a little delay it partially works.

Comment: What does the "PrintWriter" class do?

Comment: He converts and writes the given String on the Stream given as parameter "new PrintWriter(OutputStream)". So I have my socket like un C#, but in java you havent "socket.Send" and "socket.Receive". So you need to read the Inputstream of the socket and convert it to String for an equivalent of "socket.Receive" and write on the OutputStream of the socket for an equivalent of "socket.Send". And when I write on the OutputStream, the C# client reads it in his InputStream, but with "Socket.Receive".

Comment: And my prediction is that the java side is faster than the C# side so he groups multiples data in one. (Because the java side is on a server, and has probably a better ping than the client connected with the C# client)